# copy variant to char*

Tags: c++, com, variant

how to copy to a character array from variant in c++. So far I have been able to come up with the snippet below. but need help in making it work.

```
_variant_t vt_Data(parent->CharData);

if(vt_Data.vt != VT_NULL)
{
   long ubound;
   long lbound;
   long length;
   TSTHR(SafeArrayGetLBound(vt_Data.parray, 1, &lbound));
   TSTHR(SafeArrayGetUBound(vt_Data.parray, 1, &ubound));
   if(length = ubound - lbound +1)
   {
      char *char_data = new char[length];

      TSTHR(SafeArrayAccessData(vt_Data.parray, (void **) &char_data))
      memcpy(char_data, vt_Data.parray, length);
      TSTHR(SafeArrayUnaccessData(vt_Data.parray));
   }
}
```

Comment: please edit your code so it displays properly

Comment: Do you realize that the expression `if(length = ubound - lbound +1)` *assigns* `ubound - lbound +1` to `length` and then checks if `length` is non zero?  If not, use `==` to check for equality, `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: yes copy only when is length is not zero makes sense.

Comment: I think his point is the length will almost always be non-zero due to `+1` for the null. This check will also pass `lbound > ubound` and potentially allow allocation of negative length if that's a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type of `parent->CharData` is char*, bstr, or TCHAR* (or similar) then the following should work. (although untested)

```
//uses the bstr_t const assignment operator to extract the string
_bstr_t bstr = vt_Data;
```

This will create a new copy of the string.